# Sugerencias en FunctionPHP para escapar variables para MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

tengo la siguiente function

```
<php  function e($val){
    global $db;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($val));
} ?>
```

Lo que pretendo lograr es que cualquier dato en alguna de las otras funciones PHP que tenga interacción con la base de datos los mismos sean escapados antes de ser ejecutados en la función y contrarrestar la posibilidad de una inyección SQL ejemplo:

```
    <php 
// GENERAR PEDIDO
        function ingresar_dato(){
        global $db;
            // Datos recibidos del Formulario
            $a= e($_REQUEST['a']);
            $b= e($_REQUEST['b']);
            $c= e($_REQUEST['c']);
            $d= e($_REQUEST['d']); ?>
```

Se que hay métodos de consultas preparadas o PDO pero en este caso son muchas funciones que están operando y pudiera demorar meses efectuando una actualización de todas las áreas de consultas o crud a la BD y estoy tratando de implementar un método que permita escapar variables donde se intente inyectar código.

Sugerencias